# Java/JavaFX How to deal with unknown types?

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm fairly new to Java and JavaFX and I've come across a problem in which i'm not sure the best way to solve it.

```
public void goToDestination(String destination, String username, Privilege privilege) throws IOException {
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../../resources/fxml/" + destination + ".fxml"));
 Parent root = loader.load();

 SomeController controller = loader.getController();
 controller.setUsername(username);
 controller.setPrivilege(privilege);

 stage.setTitle("Yuconz System");
 stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
 stage.setMaximized(true);
 stage.show();
}
```

My problem is that I don't know what controller it will be when I'm setting the controller variable. I tried using generics but I can't then access the methods of the object. If anyone can help me understand the best way to go about this i'd be thankful.

Comment: If you do not know the type, why do you expect it to have a `setUsername` and `setPrivilege` methods ? Those must be part of a specific type.

Comment: If all of your controllers have the methods setUsername und setPrivilege, define an interface with the methods and let all controllers implement the interface. Thus you can cast your controller to that interface and use the methods.

Comment: I have a parent class called ParentController which has those methods. Is it worth doing an interface considering the methods will always have the same code?

Comment: If you address a comment to some one add @ followed by his name for example @c0der

Comment: If all your controllers extend `ParentController`, then that's all you need to know. Declare your `controller` reference as a `ParentController` instead of `SomeController`.

Comment: Thanks @Zephyr it's sorted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parent class or an interface for the controllers which contain the set methods instead of having them in all controllers. Then you can use the type ParentController.

```
public void goToDestination(String destination, String username, Privilege privilege) throws IOException {
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../../resources/fxml/" + destination + ".fxml"));
 Parent root = loader.load();

 ParentController controller = loader.getController();
 controller.setUsername(username);
 controller.setPrivilege(privilege);

 stage.setTitle("Yuconz System");
 stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
 stage.setMaximized(true);
 stage.show();
}
```